# Java Spring RESTapi @RequestMapping method not working

Tags: spring

Folks,

If i understand the API correctly, method needs to be an enum, however, the following errors out.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/greeting",method=GET)
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
            String.format(template, name));
}
```

`gradle build --info` errors out with

```
/src/main/java/hello/GreetingController.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable GET
location: class main.java.hello.GreetingController
    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting",method=GET)
```

Comment: It has indeed to be an enum but you have to either use `RequestMethod.GET` or have an `import static RequestMethod.GET` to make it work. If you don't have one of those it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/greeting",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
```

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your java file, add the following import statement:

```
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;
```

That should import the `GET` enum and you should be all set to continue coding.

This enum is part of the `spring-web` module. If you are e.g. using maven the following dependency is required:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I would not recommend `import static`

Comment: That may be but it would immediately solve the OPs problem.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

`import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;`